# Paper.js после setZoom() изображение выходит за границы

Tags: javascript

Paper.js после использования setZoom() изображение выходит за границы, как привязать зумирование к левой верхней координате, чтоб изображение зумировалось от неё?

view.setZoom();

Ожидаемый результат:
[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Сдвинутое изображение после зума:
[image: Сдвинутое изображение после зума]

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл, что мне нужно создать свой метод зуммирования с начальными координатами

```
setZoomToTopLeft: function (zoom)
{
    this.transform(new Matrix().scale(zoom / this.getZoom(),
        new Point(0, 0)));
},
```